# How to manage all Selenium tests on Java?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automation

Currently I'm executing each test by my self (using the Eclipse play button), but I'm expecting to increase the number of tests and this will not be an option anymore.

What is the correct way to automate also the execution? Should I write all test under same project, but each test at different class?

I'm looking for a way where i'll be able to select few of the tests to execute and not always all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage your tests using **TestNG** plugin. TestNG allows you to group, prioritise and control test cases execution at compile time as well as at run-time.

[TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) also allows selective test cases execution at project(package), class and method level. You can control the entire execution through a single file i.e. testng.xml .

Comment: I didn't know TestNG provide this solution. I'll check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TestNG should be able to handle all your problems.Please refer to testNG Documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

You can create test suites using TestNG and you will be able to add testcases as well as classes containing these test cases inside the suite like below.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
      
    <suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
      
      <test name="Regression1">
        <classes>
          <class name="test.sample.ParameterSample">
            <methods>
               <include name="test"/>
               <!-- Here test is method name inside ParameterSample Class-->
             </methods>
          </class>
          
        </classes>
      </test>
    </suite>
```

The above suite will run all the methods of the classes which has been added.
Now, you can control your test case at method level also i.e which method you want to run fro a particular test case inside a particular class.
You can do lot of other things also like creating a group of test cases out of some specific test cases.You can enable/disable test case etc.

Please refer documentation mentioned abovefor more Info

Comment: I learned TestNG all day today, this looks very powerful tool!  Thanks allot!